# Angular 7.2 HttpClient delete method not work, send Options method instead

Tags: angular, laravel-5, httpclient

I'm interacting with a Laravel API from Angular 7.2 component, all methods works fine except delete, I can see thru Firefox network activity console that when trigger the function, the request is sent with OPTIONS method.

This is my service method:

```
elimina( id:number ) {
return this._http.delete( this.apiFMX + '/users/' + id );}
```

And in my component:

```
eliminaElemento( id:number ) {
this.dataService.elimina( id ).subscribe();
this.ruta.navigateByUrl( '/fmx-listado' );}
```

But it doesn´t work, here the console output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN4wB.png)

Aditional I have added Cors Middleware in my Laravel API. Also, if the request is edited in the firefox console updating OPTIONS to DELETE method, it works.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advise.

Here two images of the firefox console:

[Network activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZeQA.png)

As you can see, it remains the OPTIONS method (sent by the browser), but if I edit the request and resend it updating to DELETE method, it works!

[Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjmoU.png)

This warnings are shown when fired the event, I repeat, only happens with DELETE method, PUT and GET works correctly.

This is my middleware:

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next( $request )->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*' )
      ->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' , 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' )
      ->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' , '*' );
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you put an image of the console developer?

Comment: The browser will send the OPTIONS request first before firing other methods, to see if the server will allow your intended request.  If the DELETE does not fire, you will usually error in the console.  Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Thanks, actually is not an error what the console reports, the following warnings are shown: "Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada:" and "Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada". But this only happen with DELETE method, when I use GET or POST it works correctly. My response has the proper CORS headers.

Answer (score 0):

*It's Http specifications, Not related to Angular*

---

### Solution (choose one)

1. Add your domain to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your response headers

[image]

```
// your domain : 192.168.30.104 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.30.104
```

2. Angular app and API on the same domain

---

### The cause of the problem

**Preflighted requests in CORS**

> In CORS, a preflight request with the OPTIONS method is sent, so that
> the server can respond whether it is acceptable to send the request
> with these parameters.

In particular, a request is preflighted if any of the following conditions is true:

If the request uses any of the following methods:

- PUT
- DELETE
- CONNECT
- OPTIONS
- TRACE
- PATCH

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#Preflighted_requests_in_CORS

Comment: Thanks, in fact I use a Laravel middleware to add CORS headers on the response. From Angular app when I get or update data it works fine, this only happens with DELETE method.